# Singlton для подключения к БД sqlite

Tags: c#, база-данных, sqlite

Добрый вечер.
Хочу сделать Singlton для подключения к БД Sqlite.
Чтобы не использовать по 100 раз код подключения, тк таких методов много.
Подскажите как это сделать ? Код одного из запросов ниже

```
     {
            {
                string databaseName = @"eurocar31.db";
                SQLiteConnection connection =
                      new SQLiteConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0};", databaseName));
                connection.Open();
                SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = "UPDATE Predoxraniteli SET cena =\"" + pr9.Text + "\" WHERE id = " + pr10.Text + ";";
                SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(); int index = 0;

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    index = index + 1;
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
            dataGridView5.Rows.Clear();
            getPred();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример реализован синглетон, посмотрите, метод GetConnection создает обьект один раз, после того он будет отдавать обьект ранее создан.

```
public class ConnectionDb
    {
        private static SQLiteConnection connection = null;
        private static SQLiteCommand command = null;
        private static string filePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/Database/ItemsDb.sqlite";

        /// <summary>
        /// the method returns the link to the database
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>

        public static SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
        {
            if (connection == null)
            {
                if (!File.Exists(filePath))
                    SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(filePath);

                connection = new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source={filePath};Version=3;");
                connection.Open();

                string query = "Create table if not exists `Items`( `id` INTEGER NOT NULL,`Name` varchar(30) NOT NULL, `Type` varchar(30) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))";
                command = new SQLiteCommand(query, connection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            return connection;
        }
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// The method delete existing element
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool Delete(int id = 0)
    {
        try
        {
            var query = $"Delete from `Items` where `id` = '{id}'";
            command = new SQLiteCommand(query, ConnectionDb.GetConnection());
            return Convert.ToBoolean(command.ExecuteNonQuery());
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Не совсем понял как это можно использовать в моем случае( у меня на каждой форме раз по 5 создается метод где происходит подключение и какой то запрос но к разным таблицам

Comment: Смотри, допустим ты включаешь программу, и она делает первый какой то шаг з базой, соответственно ты вызываешь метод ConnectionDb.GetConnection() и он создает подключение к базе данных, поскольку его у тебя не было, и потом если тебе снова нужно буде обратится к базе - метод возвращает существующий канал к базе данных который был создан в первый раз

Comment: Тебе нужно создать отдельный клас, в моей случае я создал ConnectionDb. Желательно создать статический класс и метод так же, чтобы он жил для всех.Данный клас будет виден всем и тебе не нужно буде создавать каждый раз новый екземпляр подключения к базе